# Internal Speakers stopped working while playing movie on vlc

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

I was watching a movie on vlc when my internal speakers suddenly stopped working, I can still hear audio via microphones but I'm not sure what happened.

I don't hear sounds through any other app as well.

I tried a few of the standard workarounds of deleting my ~/.config/pulse* caches

but that doesn't seem to have helped with anything

My alsamixer volumes are set to the max and pulseaudio/pavucontrol shows the pulse daemon is noticing a switch from headphone to speakers when i pull out the headphones but I still can't hear any sound.

This is a fairly recent lenovo laptop(~1yr) and things were working fine till yesterday

Here's a link to my alsainfo.sh script output

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=da3425b0cb643496a00ece0be10d65f40812c294

Comment: It suggests hardware failure more than anything else. Devices just don't stop working in the middle of something due to software.

Comment: and speakers are about the last possible thing that fail on a laptop. It's more likely that ubuntu has zero'd out a volume control somewhere that I can't figure out how to unzero.

Comment: You can test it in a live session. Again, although that's a possibility it's unlikely it happened in the middle of something, out of the blue.

Comment: I'm in the process of downloading and testing a live image. The code quality of pulse audio + random video codecs + vlc leaves enough room for it to be a software issue.  I also did notice something like a glitch in vlc when it happened, so it's quite possible it's related.  Does pulse, also store any settings cache outside of the user account?